# Add "org.eclipse.ui" in the Required plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse SDK-3.8.2. In my plugin.xml, in Dependencies, I would like to add "org.eclipse.ui" in the Required plug-ins. But, I can't find it. Please, what can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. What can't you find: `Dependencies` option or the plugin?

Comment: Hello, I find Depencies option. But, when I click on  "Add" to select  "org.eclipse.ui" . I don't find it .

Comment: Are you sure it is not already in the dependencies list? For a UI plugin Eclipse usually adds this when the plugin is created.

Comment: I can add "org.eclipse.ui" in the "Imported packages". But, in the  "Required plugins", I doesn't exist .

Comment: You can use the _Open Plug-in Argifacts_ dialog (press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd>) to see if the desired plug-in is contained in the current target platform at all.

Comment: Improved the grammar. I think some more improvement on the question itself is still required.